# Cyrus always displaying flag information

Tags: imap, cyrus

When I fetch a message and include FLAGS my server displays the flag information for the entire server, is there any way of removing that?

I'm using Cyrus IMAP4 v2.3.7-Invoca-RPM-2.3.7-7.el5_4.3

EX:

```
1 fetch 1 (uid flags)
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen \*)]
* 1 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen) UID 1)
1 OK Completed (0.000 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that good old imapd.conf cannot help you in this case. To modify that message you need to modify Cyrus source code.

Why is this a message a problem to you?